# How to sort a treemap based on its values?

Tags: java, treemap

How can I sort a treemap using its values rather than the key?

Comment: The first solution in this link is the best you can have.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot as the TreeMap's comparator is run against the keys only, e.g. see this [constructor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Comparator%29).

Anyway, you can use multiple Collections, use the TreeMap (or rather HashMap) for looking up elements by keys, and have a SortedSet to iterate on the values.

Answer (score 25):

Here is a solution:

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> Map<K, V> sortByValues(final Map<K, V> map) {
    Comparator<K> valueComparator =  new Comparator<K>() {
        public int compare(K k1, K k2) {
            int compare = map.get(k2).compareTo(map.get(k1));
            if (compare == 0) return 1;
            else return compare;
        }
    };
    Map<K, V> sortedByValues = new TreeMap<K, V>(valueComparator);
    sortedByValues.putAll(map);
    return sortedByValues;
}
```

Note that the map is sorted from the highest value to the lowest.

Comment: I'm getting a stackoverflow exception with this method

Comment: this is actually not working! unless all the data is in the original `Map<K,V> map` and you never need to put new values

Answer (score 6):

Google Guava provides a [TreeMultiMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html).

You could also use two collections.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Can you explain your use cases?

Answer (score 5):

[Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) has a [TreeBidiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/bidimap/TreeBidiMap.html):

> This class guarantees that the map
>   will be in both ascending key order
>   and ascending value order, sorted
>   according to the natural order for the
>   key's and value's classes.

There's a Java5-generics port of it [here](http://larvalabs.com/collections/).

Answer (score 4):

Try below code it works fine for me. You can choose both ascending as well as descending order for sorting.

```
package com.rais;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class SortMapByValue
{
    public static boolean ASC = true;
    public static boolean DESC = false;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        // Creating dummy unsorted map
        Map<String, Integer> unsortMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        unsortMap.put("B", 55);
        unsortMap.put("A", 80);
        unsortMap.put("D", 20);
        unsortMap.put("C", 70);

        System.out.println("Before sorting......");
        printMap(unsortMap);

        System.out.println("After sorting ascending order......");
        Map<String, Integer> sortedMapAsc = sortByComparator(unsortMap, ASC);
        printMap(sortedMapAsc);


        System.out.println("After sorting descindeng order......");
        Map<String, Integer> sortedMapDesc = sortByComparator(unsortMap, DESC);
        printMap(sortedMapDesc);

    }

    private static Map<String, Integer> sortByComparator(Map<String, Integer> unsortMap, final boolean order)
    {

        List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Entry<String, Integer>>(unsortMap.entrySet());

        // Sorting the list based on values
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>()
        {
            public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> o1,
                    Entry<String, Integer> o2)
            {
                if (order)
                {
                    return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
                }
                else
                {
                    return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());

                }
            }
        });

        // Maintaining insertion order with the help of LinkedList
        Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : list)
        {
            sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        return sortedMap;
    }

    public static void printMap(Map<String, Integer> map)
    {
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : "+ entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try giving a Comparator that compare values instead of keys when you create the TreeMap.

```
    final TreeMap<Integer,String> tree = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
    tree.put(1, "1");
    tree.put(2, "2");
    tree.put(3, "3");
    tree.put(4, "4");

    final TreeMap<Integer,String> treeSortedByValues = new TreeMap<Integer,String>(new Comparator<Integer>()
    {
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2)
        {
            return tree.get(o1).compareTo(tree.get(o2));
        }
    });
    treeSortedByValues.putAll(tree);

    for ( Entry<Integer, String> e : treeSortedByValues.entrySet() )
    {
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: How will the comparator get access to the values ?

Comment: It won't. This isn't possible with the TreeMap.

Comment: True, you cannot access the treemap values in the comparator since the treemap is not created yet. But you can use a temporary treemap for that...

Answer (score 0):

Swap values and keys.

More seriously, please provide some context what you want to achieve. Maybe it is enough to sort after other processing is finished.

Comment: He means you should use whatever you're using as key now as the value, and vice versa. That way you can sort on your value, which is now the key.

Comment: This is generally a poor approach since the map has unique keys (with respect to compareTo) but not necessarily unique values. Create a new map with keys swapped with values might give you a different data set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This sorts TreeMap values in ascending order, assuming that is how you want the values to be sorted.

```
static <K, V> Map<K, V> sortByValues(Map<K, V> map) {
        List<?> list = new ArrayList(map.entrySet());

        // copy Map to List to use Comparator
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) o1).getValue()).compareTo(((Map.Entry) o2).getValue());
            }
        });

        // then copy List to LinkedHashMap as it preserves insertion order
        Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
        Iterator itr = list.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<K, V> m = (Map.Entry<K, V>) itr.next();
            result.put(m.getKey(), m.getValue());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

That's I have done this..

```
package Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;

class MyComparator implements Comparator<Object> {

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return (((Integer) o2).compareTo((Integer) o1));
    }
}

class MyComparator1 implements Comparator<Object> {
    Map<Integer, String> map;

    public MyComparator1(Map<Integer, String> m) {
        this.map = m;
    }

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return (((String) map.get(o1)).compareTo((String) map.get(o2)));
    }
}

public class Map1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        hmap.put(5, "Ashok");
        hmap.put(21, "Bhanu");
        hmap.put(7, "chaman");
        hmap.put(28, "dheeraj");
        hmap.put(761, "edison");
        hmap.put(1, "frank");
        hmap.put(-6, "gopal");
        hmap.put(78, "hari");
        System.out.println("Hash Map:" + hmap);
        Map<Integer, String> tmap = new TreeMap<>(hmap);
        System.out.println("Tree Map:" + tmap);
        MyComparator comp = new MyComparator();
        Map<Integer, String> itmap = new TreeMap<>(comp);
        itmap.putAll(hmap);
        System.out.println("Tree Map Inreverse order:" + itmap);
        Map<Integer, String> orderValuemap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(new 
            MyComparator1(hmap));
            orderValuemap.putAll(hmap);
            orderValuemap.put(22,"hello");
        for(Entry<Integer, String> mp:orderValuemap.entrySet())
            System.out.println("Value : "+mp.getValue());
    }
}
```