# Unchecked call to compareTo

Tags: java, generics, collections, comparator, comparable

### Background

Create a `Map` that can be sorted by value.

### Problem

The code executes as expected, but does not compile cleanly:

http://pastebin.com/bWhbHQmT

```
public class SortableValueMap<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
  ...
  public void sortByValue() {
      ...
      Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry>() {
          public int compare( Map.Entry entry1, Map.Entry entry2 ) {
            return ((Comparable)entry1.getValue()).compareTo( entry2.getValue() );
          }
      });
  ...
```

The syntax for passing `Comparable` as a generic parameter along to the `Map.Entry<K, V>` (where `V` must be `Comparable`?) -- so that the `(Comparable)` typecast shown in the warning can be dropped -- eludes me.

### Warning

Compiler's cantankerous complaint:

> SortableValueMap.java:24: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to compareTo(T) as a member of the raw type java.lang.Comparable
>
> ```
>    return ((Comparable)entry1.getValue()).compareTo( entry2.getValue() );
> ```

### Question

How can the code be changed to compile without any warnings (without suppressing them while compiling with `-Xlint:unchecked`)?

### Related

- [TreeMap sort by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value)
- [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)
- http://paaloliver.wordpress.com/2006/01/24/sorting-maps-in-java/

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare the `V` type to extend the `Comparable<V>` interface. That way, you can remove the cast of the `Map.Entry` objects down to `(Comparable)` and use the inferred type instead:

```
public class SortableValueMap<K, V extends Comparable<V>>
             extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
```

....

```
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> entry1, Map.Entry<K, V> entry2) {
            return entry1.getValue().compareTo(entry2.getValue());
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's the ticket. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The value should be a subclass of comparable.

```
SortableValueMap<K, V extends Comparable>
```

Try the above.

Answer (score 1):

> The syntax for passing Comparable as a generic parameter along to the Map.Entry (where V must be Comparable?) -- so that the (Comparable) typecast shown in the warning can be dropped -- eludes me.

How about:

```
public class SortableValueMap <K, V extends Comparable<V>> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> { 
  ...
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> entry1, Map.Entry<K, V> entry2) {
            return (entry1.getValue()).compareTo(entry2.getValue());
        }
    });
```

but this may be better, depending on your intent:

```
public class SortableValueMap <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> { ...
```

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html

> It isn't necessary that T be comparable to exactly itself. All that's required is that T be comparable to one of its supertypes. This give us:
>
> ```
> public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>  max(Collection<T> coll)
> ```
>
> ... This reasoning applies to almost any usage of Comparable that is intended to work for arbitrary types: You always want to use `Comparable <? super T>` . ...

Comment: I went down the road of `V extends Comparable<? super V>` without success. After making the changes suggested by mhaller, I am able to use `super V`. Thank you!

Comment: @Dave - sorry about that.  I was lazy about testing it in my environment before posting.

Comment: All good, Bert. I needed to change how `Collections.sort` was being called, as per mhaller's answer. Unfortunately, I cannot mark both answers as correct. +1 though!

Comment: @Dave - Thanks.  I just wanted to make sure the answer was correct or make sure I withdraw it.  I ran the code through eclipse and added the same missing generic arguments that @mhaller added that I missed the first time.  I updated the top part of my answer (now the same mhaller's) and  I'll leave my answer for future readers to note the "You always want to use `Comparable <? super T>`" reference.