# How to sort the values of a HashMap freemarker template

Tags: java, dictionary, freemarker

I have in java this HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

     map.put("k1",  "3");
     map.put("k2", "4");
     map.put("k3", "2");
     map.put("k4", "6");
     map.put("k5", "1");
     map.put("k6", "5");
```

I print with freemarker template in this mode:

```
<#list map?values as v>
${v} - 
</#list>
```

but it prints in this order:

```
2 - 6 - 1 - 5 - 3 - 4
```

I would like to print in this order:

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5  -6
```

how can I sort values ​​with with freemarker template?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<#list map?values?sort as v>
    ${v} - 
</#list>
```

Notice the use of the `sort` builtin for the sequence of values.

Answer (score 4):

If you are displaying the values independent of the keys then you can take the values out of the map and construct a TreeSet from it. Then the values would be in order.

```
TreeSet ordered =  new TreeSet(map.values());
```

Then

```
 <#list ordered as v>
     ${v} - 
 </#list>
```

Comment: If you can add the sorted values to the model, then this is a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is predictable as HashMaps are not ordered.  As has been pointed out in the comments a SortedMap e.g. TreeMap will sort on the keys.  So you're going to have to cut some code to sort this.

See [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is not ordered. You should use a [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead which implements a [SortedMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html):-

`SortedMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();`

Please note - `Sorted Map provides a total ordering on its keys`. You **cannot** have it sorted on the values. If you want to sort on values you can always do that by sorting on the [Map.entrySet()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) using a [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) .

Also take a look at this very similar question: [TreeMap sort by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value)

Comment: `TreeMap` isn't "backed by" `SortedMap`, it implements it `</nit-pick>`

Comment: -1: `SortedMap`s are sorted on keys, not values. This is not what is asked.

Comment: @Laurent Pireyn - Care to read the full answer. I have clearly mentioned that it's sorted on keys and gave the example of how to sort on values! Please read answers fully before down voting.

Comment: @CoolBeans: I read the full answer, but still think it doesn't answer the question. You talk about sorted maps, but then admit it's not what the OP wants, and redirect him to a related question. A valid answer should provide a complete solution to the question, or at least a summary of such a solution with links to the complete version.

Comment: @Laurent Pireyn - It's mentioned in the answer with how to solve it with Map.entrySet() and Comparable. That's why I said read the full answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you need iteration over a `HashMap` in predictable order, you can use a [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) with predictable iteration order, it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries.

Comment: @Laurent, there are multiple ways to achieve a result, a hashmap that reproduces insertion order can be very useful when you need to have control over template expansion. Sort order only goes so far for non-trivial situations.

Comment: A map that conserves insertion order can be useful indeed, but that is still not what is asked here. The OP asks how to *sort* the values of the map, not how to conserve the order of their insertion.