# Groovy way of transforming a key->values map into value->keys

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to come up with a way to make keys out of a list of values.

For instance: I have this map `[ a: [1, 2], b: [1, 3, 4] ]`

I'd like to transform it into `[ 1: [a, b], 2: [a], 3: [b], 4: [b] ]`

Basically I ask for the groovy version of [How to transform key/value in Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457853/how-to-transform-key-value-in-map)
.

So far my solution is a bit excessive, because I collect all the values and create new value-key pairs:

```
def m = [ a: [1, 2], b: [1, 3, 4] ]
def transformed = m.collectMany { k, v -> v }.collectEntries { v -> [ v, [] ] }
m.collectMany { k, v -> v.collect { vi -> [ vi, k ] } }.each { v, k ->
  transformed[v] += k
}
transformed
```

Is there a better way to achieve this transformation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it this way with `inject` and `withDefault` on an empty map:

```
def m = [a: [1, 2], b: [1, 3, 4]]

m.inject([:].withDefault {[]}) { map, value ->
    value.value.each { map[it] << value.key }
    map
}
```