# Java sorting and HashMap

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, hashmap

I have a `HashMap<String, Integer>` How can I sort this data structure and keep the key-value mappings? I want to sort by VALUES not keys.

```
Collection<Integer> counts = tableFrequency.values();
```

But then I lose the key mappings. Or is there a better associative data-structure that I could have used instead of the HashMap?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2864840/1332690

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To sort a `Map` by its values, you could grab its [`entrySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29) and sort that with a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

```
List<Entry<K,V>> sorted = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(sorted, new Comparator<Entry<K,V>>() {
    public int compare(Entry<K,V> o1, Entry<K,V> o2) {
        return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
    }
};
```

Comment: I want to sort by the Values not the keys. How will this work?

Comment: Do you know what data-structure I can use to sort by values?

Comment: What library is Entry defined in?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus It looks like he statically imported Map.Entry.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus It's a nested class of `java.util.Map`.

Answer (score 2):

TreeMap keeps the elements in the order in wich you added them. It seems like a perfect answer for you.

Beware though, some actions will be way slower than with a HashMap, things such as searching...

Comment: No it doesn't, `TreeMap` will sort elements as you add them.

Comment: I want to sort by the values not the keys

Answer (score 1):

The class `TreeMap` is what you want:

```
TreeMap treeMap = new TreeMap();

treeMap.put("One", new Integer(1));
treeMap.put("Two", new Integer(2));

Object obj = treeMap.get("Two");
System.out.println(obj);
```

It uses the compare() method to be able to sort elements.

Since your new question is about sorting by values, this is a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2864840/1332690)

Comment: It seems to have sorted my keys, I want it to sort by the values

Comment: why the downvote? the original post didn't include any notion of sorting by value...