# Sort the Object's value inside the Hashmap<String, Object>

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I want to sort an Hashmap by the object's value. In this case, by country code.

```
  KEY              OBJECT                        
  String        LoyaltyCountry
                     - country name
                     - country code
                     - country loc
```

My code is as follows:

```
public static HashMap<String, LoyaltyCountry> loyaltyCountrySortMap(HashMap<String, LoyaltyCountry> loyaltyCountryMap) {

            if (loyaltyCountryMap != null) {
                List keys = new ArrayList();
                keys.addAll(loyaltyCountryMap.keySet());
                Collections.sort(keys, new Comparator<LoyaltyCountry>() {
                    public int compare(LoyaltyCountry o1, LoyaltyCountry o2) {
                        return o1.getCountryName().compareTo(o2.getCountryName());
                    }
                });
            }

            return loyaltyCountryMap;
        }
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: You're trying to sort the HashMap itself?  Or are you trying sort the keys? Or values?  Please clarify.  Your code seems to imply you want to sort the keys.

Comment: the hashmap... by the value (country name)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10167278/1332690

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to sort in it?  HashMaps are structured to provide fast put/get, and changing the sorting methods in the HashMap defeats the purpose of using a map in the first place.

Comment: I am trying to sort the Country Name... And by sorting it, the whole hashmap will be sorted accordingly...

Comment: I think you're filling a map with a list of sorted/unsorted values and then you want to sort it by value. I'll recommend to get the list already sorted and then use a `LinkedHashMap`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a method that returns a Set containing the Map.Entry items sorted by their value.

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> SortedSet<Map.Entry<K, V>> entriesSortedByValues(Map<K, V> map) {
    SortedSet<Map.Entry<K, V>> sortedEntries = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<K, V>>(
            new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> e1, Map.Entry<K, V> e2) {
                    return e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
                }
            });
    sortedEntries.addAll(map.entrySet());
    return sortedEntries;
}
```

Comment: I just happened to run into this recently so I just had to copy/paste code I already had :)

Comment: How can i change the SortedSet to HashMap?

Comment: You can probably extend HashMap and when entrySet() is called return the sorted version instead.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Comparator<Map.Entry<String,LoyaltyCountry>>`, get the `Map.entrySet()`, put it into a `List<Map.Entry<String,LoyaltyCountry>>` and sort it.

Clarification: You say you want to sort the `HashMap` by values -- that isn't going to happen. A `HashMap` is an unsorted implementation of a `Map`. Moreover, the sorted implementations of `Map` all sort on keys, so even a `TreeMap` won't help you.

The closest you can come to it (short of making your own map implementation) is produce a list of the map entries, which is what I described how to do above.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort `HashMap`.

Looks like you want to return an ordered list of map's values, sorted by country name.

For that change return type of your method to List, e.g

```
public static List<LoyaltyCountry> loyaltyCountrySortMap(
    HashMap<String, LoyaltyCountry> loyaltyCountryMap
  ) 
{

    if (loyaltyCountryMap != null) {
        List<LoyaltyCountry> values = new ArrayList();
        values.addAll(loyaltyCountryMap.values());
        Collections.sort(values, new Comparator<LoyaltyCountry>() {
            public int compare(LoyaltyCountry o1, LoyaltyCountry o2) {
                return o1.getCountryName().compareTo(o2.getCountryName());
            }
        });

        return values;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: but how can i relate it with the key?

Comment: @newbie. Follow the advice of Sarel Botha.