# How can I cast from Map.Entry<Integer,Float> to Integer in Java

Tags: java

```
 ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, Float>> list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, Float>>(datamap.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(list,new floatSort());
```

list is Map.Entry but contains only float point number. Now I want to compare the the list to other ArrayList type in Float. How can I cast from Map.Entry to float

Comment: Consider getting the values from the map: map.getValues()

Comment: Im trying to print the Map by the order of the sorted list. So I have to loop the map, find the value and then print the key.

Comment: Actually I'm using TreeMap.

Comment: John, if I understand your question right, you are trying to print your TreeMap sorted by values? If so, [this question + answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value) will help you out. @RichardJPLeGuen Thank you for showing me that meta link, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Are you using `Map.Entry` objects because you actually need the entry keys, or because you didn't know how to extract your values from their HashMap?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map.Entry.getValue.toString` and then use `Integer.parseInt` to convert the `string` to `int`

```
String value = mapentry.getValue.toString;
int intValue = Integer.parseInt(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

to get your float value from the entry you need to get the value in your comparator.

```
Map.Entry <Integer, Float> entry = ...
float f = entry.getValue ();
```