# How to sort TreeMap by value not by Key

Tags: java, treemap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TreeMap sort by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value)

Hi I want to sort TreeMap Collection by value not by its key. For eg,

```
 TreeMap map=new TreeMap();
    map.put(new Integer(100),"ccc");
    map.put(new Integer(300),"bbb");
    map.put(new Integer(200),"ddd");
    map.put(new Integer(400),"aaa");
```

It should be ordered as,

```
1) 400 -> aaa
2) 300 -> bbb
3) 100 -> ccc
4) 200 -> ddd
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value

Comment: what is the issue in using those values as keys? why do you want to force them as values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a special iterator, try this

```
...
    Iterator i = valueIterator(map);
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(i.next());
    }
...
    Iterator valueIterator(TreeMap map) {
        Set set = new TreeSet(new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<Integer, String> o1, Entry<Integer, String> o2) {
                return  o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue()) > 0 ? 1 : -1;
            }
        });
        set.addAll(map.entrySet());
        return set.iterator();
    }
```

output

```
400=aaa
300=bbb
100=ccc
200=ddd
```

You can extend TreeMap and add this method to it. Note that the Comparator allows duplicate values because it never returns 0.