# Obtain the higher number of repetitions in an ArrayList

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I have the following structure:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Movies>>
```

And The movies have duplicates, I need to obtain the n movies that have the higher number of repetitions. I've been thinking hard on this and I can't though of any elegant solution.

Comment: Sort the list with a custom comparator.

Comment: What solutions have you thought of what isn't elegant about them?

Comment: I thought of making an Array of all the movies without repetitions, and create a Comparator that compares the movies in the Array of unique movies by the frequency of them in the other array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to the following

```
HashMap<Movie, Integer> map = new HashMap<Movie, Integer>();

// ArrayList<ArrayList<Movies>> listOfList = ...initialized

for (ArrayList<Movie> list : listOfList)
{
   for (Movie movie : list)
   {
      if (map.containsKey(movie))
      {
         int count = map.get(movie);
         map.put(movie, (count+1));
      }
      else
      {
         map.put(movie, 1);
      }
   }
}
```

Make sure that you have proper implementation of `hashcode` and `equals` for this to work

Comment: I will use this with TreeMap instead of HashMap. thanks so much!

Comment: The TreeMap itself is not hassle free sorting (at least not by value).  The TreeMap sorts by Key.  So you will need to sort by value as a separate pass after adding all the elements with the Map approach

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of

```
   Map<Movie,Integer>
```

to keep

```
<movie,frequency>
```

you can search in Map or even can use TreeMap with sorting based on frequency and you can fetch first N elements from it directly.

Comment: And how do I ask for the n movies with more repetitions. Ex, I need to know the 5 more frequent movies

Answer (score 1):

This is a good time to use a Map.  The keys are the movie, and the values are the integer count. Afterwards you can create a new TreeMap to get the sorted values.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Movies>> myMovieList;
Map<Movie,Integer> map = new HashMap<Movie,Integer>();
for (List<Movie> movies : myMovieList) {
    for (Movie movie: movies){
        Integer count = map.get(movie);
        if (count == null){
            map.put(movie,1);
        } else {
            map.put(movie, count+1);
        }
    }
}
```

At the end you will have a list of Movies to their counts, and now you can sort by the values. See sorting a treemap by values, [TreeMap sort by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value), or you can just create a custom Class that is a movie and counter and put that into a list with a custom comparator.

Comment: I'm sorry, why the downvote? The answer is correct and it also has information about sorting the map afterwards to get the top n elements, which is important as a Map itself doesnt do that