# covert string from treemap to arraylist<LatLng> which was arraylist<string>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, treemap

I am getting value from treemap :

I had added to hashmap all coordinates in string format which was an rraylist now its string in treemap .So I would like to retrieve all the value from the String idlatlng which contains arraylist inside the string.:

Code added to hashmap

```
LatLng allLatLng= new LatLng((lat1),(long1));
all.add(allLatLng);

 map.put("latlng" , all.toString());
```

the second treemap:

```
      Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Map<String, String> o1, Map<String, String> o2) {
                String value1 =  o1.get("amount");
                String value2 =  o2.get("amount");
                return Integer.parseInt(value1)-Integer.parseInt(value2);
            }
        });

        for (Map<String, String> map1 : list) {
            String id = map1.get("id");
            String amount = map1.get("amount");
            System.out.println("amount= "+amount + " , " +"id = "+id);
  String idlatlng = map1.get("latlng");
        }
```

In the above code I am getting the value of latlng.

```
String idlatlng = map1.get("latlng");
```

`idlatlng` contains arraylist of  .So how do I convert the value from string above to arraylist.Its a follow up question from previous question.I really appreciate any help.Yhanks in Advance.

Output:

`String idlatlng` --->  `arraylist<LatLng>`

[Unable to sort the the list by ascending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264271/unable-to-sort-the-the-list-by-ascending-order)

The value I get from idlatlng is :  [`lat/lng: (70.0187, -141.0205), lat/lng: (70.4515,-144.8163), lat/lng: (70.4515,-144.8163), lat/lng: (70.4515,-144.8163), lat/lng: (70.4515,-144.8163), lat/lng: (70.4515,-144.8163), lat/lng: (70.4515,-144.8163), lat/lng: (70.4515,-144.8163), lat/lng: (70.4515,-144.8163)]`

Comment: Explain your question properly. Its not at all understandable. What is your problem ? What actual data your arraylist contains please show that.

Comment: Please provide some data, and your exact problem.

Comment: Are you using Json or Gson api in your project......

Comment: Hello Sir .I am using JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
private ArrayList<LatLng> latlngs = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

for (Map<String, String> map1 : list) {
String id = map1.get("id");
     String amount = map1.get("amount");              
     String idlatlng = map1.get("latlng");

     LatLng latLng = new LatLng(id , amount, idlatlng);

     latlngs.add(latLng);
```

}

Comment: Hello Remi its giving an error .Its asking me to change string idlatlng to LatLng idlatlng ?

Comment: I got this error ::::::::: The constructor LatLng(String) is undefined :::::::at  the line  :::::  new LatLng(idlatlng);

Comment: Yes you need to add those 3 Strings (id, amount, idlatlng ) to your class LatLng. So in your LatLng.class your method needs to be: public LatLng(String id, String amount, String idlatlng){ this.id = id; this.amount = amount; this.idlatlng = idlatlng; }

Answer (score 0):

```
 LatLng allLatLng= new LatLng((lat1),(long1));
 all.add(allLatLng);
 map.put("latlng" , all.toString());
```

Replace above code with this one

```
 LatLng allLatLng= new LatLng((lat1),(long1));
 all.add(allLatLng);    
 JSONArray jsonA = JSONArray.fromObject(all);
 map.put("latlng" , jsonA.toString());
```

Your iteration would look like below

```
  for (Map<String, String> map1 : list) {
       String id = map1.get("id");
       String amount = map1.get("amount");
       System.out.println("amount= "+amount + " , " +"id = "+id);
       JSONArray jsonArray =  JSONArray.fromObject( map1.get("lanlat"));
       Collection<LatLng> collection = JSONArray.toCollection(jsonArray, LatLng.class);                       
       for (Iterator iterator = collection.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
           LatLng latLng = (LatLng) iterator.next();
           //Do whatever with your latLng object            
       }
  }
```

Note:
To work properly LatLng class should have defualt constructor.

if you need more details let me know.........