# Sorting LinkedHashMap by value

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

How can you sort a LinkedHashMap   using the value ?

Is there a way to insert entries into a LinkedHashMap so that they are inserted in order based on their value ?

Comment: What is the purpose of using a `LinkedHashMap` when you sort it? Maybe use a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead and provide an own [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to sort the value instead of the key.

Comment: The whole point of it being "Linked" is to derive the benefits of a List, i.e. indexed access. If you want default sorting, you'll need a Tree-based data structure

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> How can you sort a LinkedHashMap using the value?

`LinkedHashMap` is not *sorted*, it is *ordered* by order of insertion.

If your goal is to *reorder* the Map, you might do something like

```
static <K, V> void orderByValue(
        LinkedHashMap<K, V> m, final Comparator<? super V> c) {
    List<Map.Entry<K, V>> entries = new ArrayList<>(m.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> lhs, Map.Entry<K, V> rhs) {
            return c.compare(lhs.getValue(), rhs.getValue());
        }
    });

    m.clear();
    for(Map.Entry<K, V> e : entries) {
        m.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
}
```

We put all the entries in a List, sort the List, then put the entries back in the Map in the new order.

Here's a Java 8 translation for those inclined:

```
static <K, V> void orderByValue(
        LinkedHashMap<K, V> m, Comparator<? super V> c) {
    List<Map.Entry<K, V>> entries = new ArrayList<>(m.entrySet());
    m.clear();
    entries.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue, c))
        .forEachOrdered(e -> m.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
}
```

(Which, out of curiosity, can be condensed to, although it is less efficient):

```
static <K, V> void orderByValue(
        LinkedHashMap<K, V> m, Comparator<? super V> c) {
    new ArrayList<>(m.keySet()).stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(m::get, c))
        .forEachOrdered(k -> m.put(k, m.remove(k)));
}
```

> Is there a way to insert entries into a LinkedHashMap so that they are inserted in order based on their value?

No. See above. `LinkedHashMap` is not sorted.

If your goal is to *keep the Map sorted*, you need to use a `TreeMap`; however there are problems with doing so. Entries in the Map need to have unique values. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java).

Comment: Elegant and minimal. How about a Java 8 version too - as a challenge. :D

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza If you mean using a temp `TreeMap` to sort the `LinkedHashMap` (e.g. `TreeMap<...> tm = new TreeMap<>(lhm, valueComparator); lhm.clear(); lhm.putAll(tm);`), I don't really think it is a good idea. Either values then need to be unique or you need [a hack Comparator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4702335/2891664).

Comment: Even eleganter -<grin>

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Sure, the method could accept `Map`, but it wouldn't have an effect. I suppose it would be nice if Java had an interface like `OrderedMap<K, V>` which `LinkedHashMap` could implement, even if it was just a marker.

Comment: What's the point in declaring parameters in the function header like this -> `static <K, V> void orderByValue`? I just don't get it... isn't this syntax normally used for parametrized types? This chunk doesn't seem to have anything to parametrize, as far as I know... can somebody explain it, please?

Comment: @SebasSBM It lets us work with the map in a more type-safe way, without us knowing its actual type. In this case, the main benefit is that it lets us pass in a comparator which is compatible with the value type of the map. (`Comparator<? super V>` is basically just a `Comparator<V>`, but it's a little more permissive about what you can pass in to the method.) You could write an equivalent method without the type parameters by [using raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2891664), but raw types are discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to sort a `LinkedHashMap` by value is to write a comparator that compares two `Map.Entry<K,V>` objects by value, then

```
Map.Entry<K,V>[] entries = (Map.Entry<K,V>[])map.entrySet().toArray();
Arrays.sort(entries, comparator);
```

The comparator would look something like

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<K,V>> comparator = new Comparator<Map.Entry<K,V>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<K,V> o1, Map.Entry<K,V> o2) {
        return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
    }
};
```

Basically, it's the obvious thing: create an array of all the key/value pairs in the map, and then sort it.
**NOTE:** I haven't tested this.

As for the second question: this would require a special data structure that maintains the values in order.  When you insert an element, it would set up the hash table *and* maintain a doubly-linked list of the elements in insertion order *and* set up some sort of AVL tree to keep the values in order like `TreeSet`.  I don't think Java defines a class like this, but maybe there's one in a third-party library.  It might be easiest to maintain two separate structures, a `LinkedHashMap<K,V>` and a `TreeSet<Map.Entry<K,V>>`.

Answer (score 2):

Like the answer before me suggested a LinkedHashMap is not sorted it only holds the insertion order. You have to manually create your comparator.

now the question is what do you what to sort the Map by ? By an integer key...

Here is a example: (Tree Map)

### Default Compare

```
           // Create a hash map
          TreeMap tm = new TreeMap();
          // Put elements to the map
          tm.put("person1", new Double(1));
          tm.put("person2", new Double(2));
          tm.put("person3", new Double(3));
          tm.put("person4", new Double(4));
          tm.put("person5", new Double(5));
          
          // Get a set of the entries
          Set set = tm.entrySet();
          // Get an iterator
          Iterator i = set.iterator();
          // Display elements
          while(i.hasNext()) {
             Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
             System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
             System.out.println(me.getValue());
          }
          System.out.println();
          
          // Deposit 1000 into person5's account
          double balance = ((Double)tm.get("person5")).doubleValue();
          tm.put("person5", new Double(balance + 1000));
          System.out.println("person5's new balance: " +
          tm.get("person5"));
```

This tree will sort in the natural order of the keys. i.e. person1 threw person5

```
    person1: 1.00
    person2: 2.00
    person3: 3.00
    person4: 4.00
    person5: 5.00
    person5's new balance: 1005.00
```

### Use a custom comparator:

```
public class MyTMCompUserDefine {
 
    public static void main(String a[]){
        //By using name comparator (String comparison)
        TreeMap<Empl,String> tm = new TreeMap<Empl, String>(new MyNameComp());
        tm.put(new Empl("Ram",3000), "RAM");
        tm.put(new Empl("John",6000), "JOHN");
        tm.put(new Empl("Crish",2000), "CRISH");
        tm.put(new Empl("Tom",2400), "TOM");
        Set<Empl> keys = tm.keySet();
        for(Empl key:keys){
            System.out.println(key+" ==> "+tm.get(key));
        }
        System.out.println("===================================");
        //By using salary comparator (int comparison)
        TreeMap<Empl,String> trmap = new TreeMap<Empl, String>(new MySalaryComp());
        trmap.put(new Empl("Ram",3000), "RAM");
        trmap.put(new Empl("John",6000), "JOHN");
        trmap.put(new Empl("Crish",2000), "CRISH");
        trmap.put(new Empl("Tom",2400), "TOM");
        Set<Empl> ks = trmap.keySet();
        for(Empl key:ks){
            System.out.println(key+" ==> "+trmap.get(key));
        }
    }
}
 
class MyNameComp implements Comparator<Empl>{
 
    @Override
    public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) {
        return e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName());
    }
}
 
class MySalaryComp implements Comparator<Empl>{
 
    @Override
    public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) {
        if(e1.getSalary() > e2.getSalary()){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
 
class Empl{
     
    private String name;
    private int salary;
     
    public Empl(String n, int s){
        this.name = n;
        this.salary = s;
    }
     
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Name: "+this.name+"-- Salary: "+this.salary;
    }
}

Output:
Name: Crish-- Salary: 2000 ==> CRISH
Name: John-- Salary: 6000 ==> JOHN
Name: Ram-- Salary: 3000 ==> RAM
Name: Tom-- Salary: 2400 ==> TOM
===================================
Name: Crish-- Salary: 2000 ==> CRISH
Name: Tom-- Salary: 2400 ==> TOM
Name: Ram-- Salary: 3000 ==> RAM
Name: John-- Salary: 6000 ==> JOHN
```

Comment: I want to sort by the value so I though there was no point creating a tree map if I was going to override the default sort.

Answer (score 0):

Convert LinkedHashMap to sorted List and then do what you want:

```
        LinkedHashMap<String, BigDecimal> topCosts = data.getTopCosts();
        List<Map.Entry<String, BigDecimal>> entries = topCosts.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted((o1, o2) -> o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue())) // desc
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (Map.Entry<String, BigDecimal> entry : entries) {
            // do somting..
        }
```