# Reverse order based on value with HashMap?

Tags: java

The HashMap used is:

```
public static HashMap<User,Integer> onlineUsers = new HashMap<User,Integer>();
```

Lets say I add values like this:

```
onlineUsers.put(myUserObj,1);
onlineUsers.put(myUserObj,5);
onlineUsers.put(myUserObj,2);
```

How can I print the values out in descending order?

```
5
2
1
```

I've seen how do to this with a TreeMap but the Key in this case cannot be an integer.

Comment: Hash maps are unordered.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap are only pairs of `key/value` and are in no way ordered.

However, it is possible to sort a `Map` by Value using a SortedSet of `Map.entry` see this post for how to do it [TreeMap sort by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value)

Comment: I used a TreeMap and Collections.sort, but I came across this exception: 'cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable' for my User object.

Comment: A TreeMap does not sort by values.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
// for each value
map.values()
   // sort them in reverse order
   .sort(Collections.reverseOrder())
   // and print each one
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Say you want to sort the keys by decreasing value.  You can do this.

```
map.entrySet()
   .sort(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue()).reversed())
   .map(Map.Entry::getKey())
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

A Map does not sort by values. Some of them (like TreeMap) sort by key, some of them (like HashMap) don't sort at all.

So what you need to do is get the Collection of values and sort those.

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
Collections.sort(values, Collections.reverseOrder())
```

Answer (score -1):

Since as per you, treeMap is not an option, you can iterator through your hashmap and save the value in a temporary arrayList. Now use sort operation on that and then output the results.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to iterator in the order that you add the elements, you should use a **[LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).**

The TreeMap is an ordered map. This implies that it uses the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) or [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface to sort the elements. It sorts (and iterates) based on how it compares to other elements. The LinkedHashMap will sort based on the order that you insert the elements.