# Comparator for Sorting a Map

Tags: java, dictionary, comparator

Hope you're doing well. I am having some trouble implementing the comparator method to sort a map by its values. I have written the comparator method, and am now trying to write a method that takes in an unsorted map as input, and uses the comparator implementation to return a sorted `Map`. However, there is an error in one of the lines in my code which prevents it from compiling. The code for the sorting method I wrote is given below:

```
public static HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>strongSorter(HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> unsortedMap) {

    MapComparator myCompare = new MapComparator(unsortedMap);
    HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> sortedMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>(myCompare);
    sortedMap.putAll(unsortedMap);
    return sortedMap;
}
```

The error is present in the line where I try and create my sortedMap; Eclipse states that I am not allowed to pass in myCompare as an argument since my inputted arguments must match the inputs to a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`. I don't know how to get around this and would really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: sorting a... HashMap?

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a sorted `HashMap`. From the Javadoc (emphasis mine):

> Hash table based implementation of the Map interface. This
>   implementation provides all of the optional map operations, and
>   permits null values and the null key. (The HashMap class is roughly
>   equivalent to Hashtable, except that it is unsynchronized and permits
>   nulls.) **This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map;
>   in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain
>   constant over time.**

If you want ordering in your map, you should use a [`SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), such as [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). Also, note that `TreepMap` sorts by the keys, so you may have to [try another approach to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value).

You could do this in Java 8 by using the `comparingByValue()` method in [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue--). Here is an example that returns a `Stream` sorted by the maps values:

```
public static Stream<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> strongSorter(Map<String, List<String>> unsortedMap) {
    return unsortedMap.entrySet()
                      .stream()
                      .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(new MapComparator()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TreeMap as sorted map and specify your comparator.