# TreeMap putall issue while using new comparator

Tags: java

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> map1 = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
map1.put("A", 1); map1.put("B", 2); map1.put("C", 3);
TreeMap<String, Integer> map2 = new TreeMap<>((str1, str2) -> map1.get(str1) - map1.get(str2) > 0 ? -1 : 1);
map2.putAll(map1);
Iterator<String> iterator = map2.keySet().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = iterator.next();
        System.out.println(key + "  " + map2.get(key) + " " + map1.get(key));
}
```

Output of this is

```
C  null 3

B  null 2

A  null 1
```

Please explain why I am getting null values from `map2`, even after doing `map2.putAll(map1)`

Strangely when I iterate through entry iterator is giving the right output

```
    Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> entryIterator = map2.entrySet().iterator();
    while(entryIterator.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, Integer> entry = entryIterator.next();
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

EDIT 
As answered issue was with comparator. It is working with

```
    TreeMap<String, Integer> map2 = new TreeMap<>((str1, str2) -> str1.equals(str2) ? 0 : map1.get(str1) - map1.get(str2) > 0 ? -1 : 1);
```

Comment: Have you debugged the `putAll` operation?

Comment: Not related to the question but your comparison logic is prone to integer overflow issues.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed returning zero in the comparator when the map values are equal:

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> map2 = new TreeMap<>(
    new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
            if(map1.get(str1).equals(map1.get(str2))) {
                return 0;
            }
            return map1.get(str1) - map1.get(str2) > 0 ? -1 : 1;
        }
    });
```

From the documentation of [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> Note that the ordering maintained by a tree map, like any sorted map, and whether or not an explicit comparator is provided, must be *consistent with `equals`* if this sorted map is to correctly implement the Map interface. (See `Comparable` or `Comparator` for a precise definition of *consistent with equals*.) This is so because the `Map` interface is defined in terms of the `equals` operation, **but a sorted map performs all key comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method**, so two keys that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted map, equal. The behavior of a sorted map is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with `equals`; it just fails to obey the general contract of the `Map` interface.

Comment: I have not added 0, since it will override the keys in case two values are same. Anyway question is why I am getting null values, while key is there.

Comment: @ankushb You're getting null because the comparator implementation is wrong again. The `TreeMap` relies on the comparator to check the existence of a key.

Comment: @manouti This still prints *A null 1*. Also, I don't completely understand why the values are `null` when it's the keys that are the ones being sorted.

Comment: @CKing The OP is sorting `map2` by value, not by key. In this case, the `TreeMap` has a comparator that is inconsistent with the `Object.equals()` method contract, hence it cannot find a value corresponding to a key.

Comment: @manouti I skimmed through the code and assumed that the OP was sorting on the keys. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Check the TreeMap source code

```
final Entry<K,V> getEntryUsingComparator(Object key) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        K k = (K) key;
    Comparator<? super K> cpr = comparator;
    if (cpr != null) {
        Entry<K,V> p = root;
        while (p != null) {
            int cmp = cpr.compare(k, p.key);
            if (cmp < 0)
                p = p.left;
            else if (cmp > 0)
                p = p.right;
            else
                return p;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

it using comparator to get the entry, like binary search.
your comparator return 0, then TreeMap never can find the entry, so return null.