# Java HashMap sort by value then key

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I am trying to sort a HashMap first by value (integer) then by key (string). The following method doesn't appear to be sorting the hashmap properly. Any ideas how to make it work properly ?

```
private static Map<String, Integer> sortHash(Map<String, Integer> map) {
    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());

    // Sort list by integer values then by string keys
    Collections.sort(list, (a, b) -> {
        int cmp1 = a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue());
        if (cmp1 != 0)
            return cmp1;
        else
            return a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey());
    });

    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : list)
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());

    return result;
}
```

Comment: A better implementation of your comparator would be `list.sort(Map.Entry.comparingByValue().thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))`

Comment: @LouisWasserman Would i have to call this after i initialize my list ? [This](https://i.gyazo.com/ce3ee598b13c5044f10d18771d56357c.png) is what I am seeing. Not sure what exactly I am missing.

Comment: Will you not have a problem where you are just putting your results into a HashMap which has no guaranteed order? I think you'll need to look at TreeMap and supply a comparator to that. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
```

Use `LinkedHashMap` since this map will maintain the order of the addition of the key/value pairs.