# Getting errors in writing customize sorting for TreeMap in Java

Tags: java, collections

Below is my class Emp and Class Mycomparator which implements Comparator.
Both are in same package . I am getting error as The constructor TreeMap(Mycomparator) is undefined. I am new to Java. Please help.

```
public class Emp {

    String name;
    int eid;

    public Emp(String name, int eid){
        this.name=name;
        this.eid = eid;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Emp e1 = new Emp("shankar",333);
        Emp e2 = new Emp("Ronaldo",222);
        Emp e3 = new Emp("Messi",111);
        TreeMap<Integer,Emp> e = new TreeMap<Integer,Emp>(new Mycomparator());
        e.put(1, e1);
        e.put(2, e2);
        e.put(3, e3);

        Set<Integer> ss = e.keySet();
        for(Integer i:ss) {
            Emp ee = (Emp) e.get(i);
            System.out.println(i+"--------"+ee.eid+"======="+ee.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my class name Mycomparator which implements  Comparator Interface.

```
public class Mycomparator  implements Comparator<Entry<Integer,Emp>> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<Integer,Emp> arg0, Entry<Integer,Emp> arg1) {
        Map.Entry<Integer,Emp> obj1 = arg0;
        Map.Entry<Integer,Emp> obj2 = arg1;
        Emp e1 = (Emp) obj1.getValue();
        Emp e2 =(Emp) obj2.getValue();
        return  e1.name.compareTo(e2.name); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `TreeMap` takes a `Comparator<K>` **not** a `Comparator<Entry<K, V>>` - this is your mistake.

Answer (score 3):

A sorted `Map` is sorted by *keys*, not values, and the only available option is to sort by the key (`Integer`), not the "entry". If you want to sort by values, you'll need to write your own map. I'm not aware of any library implementation that sorts by value.

Comment: Did you mean "values" for that last word?

Comment: There are plenty of questions on this site about sorting a `TreeMap` by value - [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value). Might be worth linking one. +1 either way

Comment: @BoristheSpider Except all of them are looking at postprocessing the map by inverting it and sorting then. I didn't want to muddy the (already confused) waters.

Comment: Some of them work by calling `get` from the `Map` in the `Comparator` - but you're probably right; no need to add more complexity.