# Sort a hash map which contains set of an objects

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I have a hashmap of a structure: `Map<Integer,Set<class-object>> mymap = new HashMap<>()`
In the map key is the integer and values are set of class objects
The class-object has the following variables in it

```
{
  Integer id 
  String name
}
```

I want to sort the map in alphabetical order based on the `class-object.name` variable.
How can we sort this map? Is it possible to sort such type of hashmap?

Comment: what object are you referring to? Have you tried anything?

Comment: duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value

Answer (score 2):

You can't. HashMap cannot be sorted, since they are hashed instead.

Either use a TreeMap to keep your keys in order, or put your data in a List so that you can put them in whatever order you want, included sorted order by calling sort().

Answer (score 1):

Flatten the sets to a single list like so :

```
List<MyObject> allObj = myMap.values().forEach(list::addAll);
```

Then sort the list :

```
allObj.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.name));
```