# Java 8 stream HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> to SortedMap<String, Integer>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> professions`, and I want to create a `SortedMap<String, Integer>` where the first entry is a string same to the first entry of the hashmap, and second entry is an Integer equal to the size of the ArrayList in the first map corresponding to the string. I also want that the sortedMap is sorted by the first entry (the string).

I tryed the following:

```
professions.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), TreeMap::new,
                    Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getValue().size()));
```

Eclipse tells me `The method mapping(Function<? super T,? extends U>, Collector<? super U,A,R>) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> e) -> {})` and also `The method getValue() is undefined for the type T`.

I'm not sure if my solution is wrong at all, or it's just eclipse that can't infer type.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `toMap` collector as opposed to the `groupingBy`:

```
Map<String, Integer> resultSet = 
     professions.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                        e -> e.getValue().size(),
                        (left, right) -> left, TreeMap::new));
```

Comment: Thanks!
Can you explain me "(left, right) -> left, TreeMap::new"?
How does it work? Can't I just type "TreeMap::new"?

Comment: @SimoneDeVita there are **three** [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) collectors and there is only one that allows you to specify the map implementation you want and since you're specifically wanting a `TreeMap` hence the `TreeMap::new`. the `(left, right) -> left` will never be called in this specific case but **it is** required in order to use this overload of `toMap`.

Comment: The `(left, right) -> left` is the [merge function](https://www.concretepage.com/java/jdk-8/java-8-convert-list-to-map-using-collectors-tomap-example#merge), needed when the `toMap()` method finds duplicate keys. As said by @Aominè in this case is never called (since its impossible to have duplicate keys), but needed to call the overloaded method with the `Supplier` parameter.

Comment: Excellent explanations! Thank you guys.

Comment: @Aominè If he were to sort the `TreeMap` by value, could he do that inline? and how? Instead of `TreeMap::new`, can you use a comparator, `TreeMap(Comparator)` and sort by value that way?

Comment: @JackFlamp passing a comparator only allows you to control how the **keys** of the map are to be sorted not the values. that said, there are workarounds you can do. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value)

Comment: You may use `(left, right) -> { throw new AssertionError(); }` instead, to indicate the assumption that it will never be called. That’s preferable to silently getting *some* result, if the assumption turns out to be false (e.g., if someone modifies the code in the future or the input is an `IdentityHashMap`).