# TreeMap Customized Comparator

Tags: java, comparator, treemap

So I want to use TreeMap with a customized comparator
My key is a String: id, my value is an int: count;
**I NEED TO COMPARE THE COUNT, AS THE VALUE(INTEGER) IN THE TREEMAP**
So I have:

**In one class:**

```
import java.util.*;

public TreeMap<String, Integer> tm = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(new SortIdCount<Integer>());
```

**In another class:**

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SortIdCount implements Comparator<Integer>{

    public int compare(Integer count1, Integer count2) {
        return count1.compareTo(count2);
    }

}
```

It shows error in eclipse:

```
The type SortIdCount is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer>
```

Comment: You probably need a `Comparator<String>` as `String` is the type of your map key.

Comment: You can't (really) use a `TreeMap` to sort by values, only by keys.

Comment: @Hovercraft Did your edit just change the code?  I don't recall seeing a diamond `<Integer>` in the original version.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: un-formatted code will not show the diamond, but it was there all the time, just not showing. Please check the edit history to see that this is correct. I certainly did not change his code, just indented it.

Comment: Below Link Might help to to sort tree map on values 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value

Answer (score 1):

> The type SortIdCount is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with
>   arguments < Integer >

Reason : Class `SortIdCount` is not **genric** type so you can not pass **parameterized** argument.
Error At Line : `(new SortIdCount<Integer>()`

> Note : A TreeMap is always sorted based on its keys, however if you
>   want to sort it based on its values then you can build a logic to do
>   this using comparator. Below is a complete code of sorting a TreeMap
>   by values.

**To Sort on Values You can refer below code snippet.**

```
import java.util.*;

public class TreeMapDemo {
  //Method for sorting the TreeMap based on values
  public static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> Map<K, V> 
    sortByValues(final Map<K, V> map) {
    Comparator<K> valueComparator = 
             new Comparator<K>() {
      public int compare(K k1, K k2) {
        int compare = 
              map.get(k1).compareTo(map.get(k2));
        if (compare == 0) 
          return 1;
        else 
          return compare;
      }
    };

    Map<K, V> sortedByValues = 
      new TreeMap<>(valueComparator);
    sortedByValues.putAll(map);
    return sortedByValues;
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    TreeMap<String, Integer> treemap = new TreeMap<>();

    // Put elements to the map
    treemap.put("Key1", 5);
    treemap.put("Key2", 4);
    treemap.put("Key3", 3);
    treemap.put("Key4", 2);
    treemap.put("Key5", 1);

    // Calling the method sortByvalues
    Map sortedMap = sortByValues(treemap);

    // Get a set of the entries on the sorted map
    Set set = sortedMap.entrySet();

    // Get an iterator
    Iterator i = set.iterator();

    // Display elements
    while(i.hasNext()) {
      Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
      System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
      System.out.println(me.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

For more details refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value)

Comment: but i don't need to compare key in the string, i need to compare the value in integer

Comment: @wnl2367 is this information mentioned into question ?

Answer (score 1):

As others might already have mentioned, that the `Comparator` used in the [TreeMap constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Comparator)) is used to **sort** the map by **key**.

> public TreeMap(Comparator comparator)
>
> ... ordered according to the given comparator. All **keys** inserted into the map must be mutually comparable by the given comparator: comparator.compare(k1, k2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any keys k1 and k2 in the map...

But if you want to sort a map by the **value**, still we have a solution using [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) as:

```
    Map<String, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
    treeMap.put("hi", 1);
    treeMap.put("there", 3);
    treeMap.put("hey", 2);
    treeMap = treeMap.entrySet().stream().sorted((e1, e2) -> e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (oldV, newV) -> oldV, LinkedHashMap::new));
    System.out.println(treeMap);
```

Output:

```
{there=3, hey=2, hi=1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `TreeMap` which sort by value. There are so many ways to sort a map by value but I believe TreeMap is not for that. If you look on the TreeMap constructor: `TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator)` which takes comparator as an argument which's generic type clearly should be the `super of Key of the Map`. So it impossible to send a `Comparator<Integer>` when the key is `String`.

Please follow the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value) for sorting Map by value.

Answer (score 0):

The comparator used for a TreeMap has to compare the keys, not the values.

So the comparison would have to take the passed key and look up the value in the map. And there you have a classical hen (map) and egg (comparator) problem. You need the comparator to create the map, but since the comparator has to look into the map, you need the map for the comparator. You could solve this by having `comparator.setMap(map)` after creation of the map.

But the most critical problem is, that your map will not work. As long as the entry is not written to the map, you don't have the value, so the comparator won't work. Only idea I have for that is using two maps. Both String, Integer. The first one is simply used for the lookup in the comparator. So you always have to put into the first and then into the second.

And then you still have problems, because you might easily violate the `SortedMap` contract. A key must not change (regarding the sorting) after it is inserted into the map. But as soon as you put another value, you have a different sorting of the key.

So I'd really rethink your requirements and whether a TreeMap is the best solution to what you need.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class SortIdCount implements Comparator<String> {

    public int compare(String count1, String count2) {
        return count1.compareTo(count2);
    }
}
```