# How to collect to Map<String, List<String>> to acheve that List is sorted?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have code like this:

```
final TreeMap<String, List<MyBean>> map= elements.stream()
                .filter(....)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyBean::getName,
                        TreeMap::new,
                        Collectors.toList()
                ));
```

How to achieve that List is sorted by `someStringField` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `Collectors#collectingAndThen` to your `Collectors#toList` downstream:

```
final TreeMap<String, List<MyBean>> map = elements.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyBean::getName,
              TreeMap::new,
              Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                      Collectors.toList(),
                      l -> {
                          l.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyBean::getSomeStringField));
                          return l;
                      })
      ));
```

Comment: hmmm... it leads to compile error. Could you please check it ?

Comment: Error:(50, 21) java: incompatible types: inference variable RR has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.util.List<my.gcp.samples.ExampleController.MyBean>,D,V
    lower bounds: void

Comment: Looks like you missed **return l;** statement.

Comment: @gstackoverflow Thank you for the edit. I haven't tried it out before, it was just written on the fly.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you check the solution proposed in another thread:
[TreeMap sort by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value)

It seams you have to pass by SortedSet. TreeMap itself would not be sortable.