# Sort a list of Java objects by multiple fields and group by a particular field

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-7

I am trying to sort a List of Java objects according to more than one field. The object is of type:

```
public class Employee {
    String empId;
    String groupId;
    String salary;
    ...
}
```

All the employees with same groupId must be grouped together. groupId can be null. The group with the highest total salary (sum of salaries of all the employees in a group) must be at the top of the list. The list must be in descending order. In each group employees must be sorted in the decreasing order of their salaries.

Example: Given data:

```
+-------+---------+--------+--+
| empId | groupId | salary |  |
+-------+---------+--------+--+
| emp1  | grp1    |    500 |  |
| emp2  | null    |    600 |  |
| emp3  | null    |    700 |  |
| emp4  | grp2    |    800 |  |
| emp5  | grp1    |    700 |  |
| emp6  | grp2    |   1000 |  |
| emp7  | grp1    |    800 |  |
| emp8  | null    |   1000 |  |
| emp9  | grp2    |    600 |  |
+-------+---------+--------+--+
```

Expected output:

```
+-------+---------+--------+
| empId | groupId | salary |
+-------+---------+--------+
| emp6  | grp2    |   1000 |
| emp4  | grp2    |    800 |
| emp9  | grp2    |    600 |
| emp8  | null    |   1000 |
| emp3  | null    |    700 |
| emp2  | null    |    600 |
| emp7  | grp1    |    800 |
| emp5  | grp1    |    700 |
| emp1  | grp1    |    500 |
+-------+---------+--------+
```

My solution:

```
public class Employee {
    String empId;
    String groupId;
    int salary;

    ...

    public String getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(String empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    ...

}

class EmployeeChainedComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

    private List<Comparator<Employee>> listComparators;

    public EmployeeChainedComparator(Comparator<Employee>... comparators) {
        this.listComparators = Arrays.asList(comparators);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
        for (Comparator<Employee> comparator : listComparators) {
            int result = comparator.compare(o1, o2);
            if (result != 0)
                return result;
        }

        return 0;
    }

}

class EmployeeGroupComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
        if(o2.getGroupId() == null)
            return (o1.getGroupId() == null) ? 0 : -1;
        if(o1.getGroupId() == null)
            return 1;
        return o1.getGroupId().compareTo(o2.getGroupId());
    }

}


class EmployeeSalaryComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
        return o2.getSalary() - o1.getSalary();
    }

}

class Solution {
    void sortEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        Collections.sort(employees, new EmployeeChainedComparator(new EmployeeGroupComparator(), new EmployeeSalaryComparator()))
    }
}
```

Comment: "I am trying to sort a List..." - then you should show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: A solution that comes to my mind would be to create a helper map with groupId and total salary and then sort based on that with some comparator.

Comment: I used a chain comparator to sort by groupId and salary but i couldn't figure to sort it by total sum of the group.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I am working on a older version of Java(7) and cannot use Streams.

Comment: Post whatever code you have written.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash, I edited the question and added the solution i tried.

Comment: Here's what I would do.  1) Sort the List<Employee> in descending salary order.  2) Create a summary list, grouping by groupID, and calculating total salary.  You can do this with either SQL or code, 3) Looping through the groupIDs of the summary list, pull out the employees from the List<Employee> that are already sorted in descending salary order.  In your example, the first groupID would be grp2, then null, then grp1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you have posted seems to be too complex for this problem. Given below is a clean approach for solving it:

1. Sort employees using the comparators defined in the class, `Solution`.
2. Group employees by group ID with the sum of salary as the grouping function. In other words, create a `Map` in which `groupId` will be the key and the sum of salaries pertaining to the `groupId` will be the value.
3. Iterate the sorted entry set of `map` created in step#2 and put the records corresponding to each entry into the result list.

   Given below is the code implementing the above-mentioned algorithm:

   ```
   // Sort employees using the comparators defined in the class, Solution
   new Solution().sortEmployees(empList);

   // Group employees by group ID with the sum of salary as the grouping function
   Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
   for (Employee e : empList) {
       String grp = e.getGroupId();
       if (grp == null) {
           grp = "null";
       }
       Integer salary = map.get(grp);
       map.put(grp, salary == null ? e.getSalary() : e.getSalary() + salary);
   }

   // Result list
   List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<>();

   // Iterate the sorted entry set of `map` and put the records corresponding to
   // an entry into the result list
   for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : entriesSortedByValues(map)) {
       String grp = entry.getKey();
       int i;

       // Find the starting index of `grp` in empList

       if ("null".equals(grp)) {// Special handling for employees with `null` group
           // Find the index in `empList` where employees with the group as `null` starts
           for (i = 0; i < empList.size() && empList.get(i).getGroupId() != null; i++)
               ;

           // Add elements before a different group is encountered
           for (int j = i; j < empList.size() && empList.get(j).getGroupId() == null; j++) {
               result.add(empList.get(j));
           }
       } else {
           // Find the index in `empList` where employees with the group as `grp` starts
           for (i = 0; i < empList.size() && !grp.equals(empList.get(i).getGroupId()); i++)
               ;

           // Add elements before a different group is encountered
           for (int j = i; j < empList.size() && grp.equals(empList.get(j).getGroupId()); j++) {
               result.add(empList.get(j));
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   ### Demo

   ```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.Collections;
   import java.util.Comparator;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.Map;
   import java.util.Map.Entry;
   import java.util.Objects;
   import java.util.SortedSet;
   import java.util.TreeSet;

   class Employee {
       String empId;
       String groupId;
       int salary;

       public Employee(String empId, String groupId, int salary) {
           this.empId = empId;
           this.groupId = groupId;
           this.salary = salary;
       }

       public String getEmpId() {
           return empId;
       }

       public String getGroupId() {
           return groupId;
       }

       public int getSalary() {
           return salary;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object obj) {
           Employee other = (Employee) obj;
           return Objects.equals(empId, other.empId) && Objects.equals(groupId, other.groupId)
                   && Objects.equals(salary, other.salary);
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "Employee [empId=" + empId + ", groupId=" + groupId + ", salary=" + salary + "]";
       }
   }

   class EmployeeChainedComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

       private List<Comparator<Employee>> listComparators;

       public EmployeeChainedComparator(Comparator<Employee>... comparators) {
           this.listComparators = Arrays.asList(comparators);
       }

       @Override
       public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
           for (Comparator<Employee> comparator : listComparators) {
               int result = comparator.compare(o1, o2);
               if (result != 0)
                   return result;
           }

           return 0;
       }

   }

   class EmployeeGroupComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

       @Override
       public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
           if (o2.getGroupId() == null)
               return (o1.getGroupId() == null) ? 0 : -1;
           if (o1.getGroupId() == null)
               return 1;
           return o1.getGroupId().compareTo(o2.getGroupId());
       }

   }

   class EmployeeSalaryComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

       @Override
       public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
           return o2.getSalary() - o1.getSalary();
       }

   }

   class Solution {
       void sortEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
           Collections.sort(employees,
                   new EmployeeChainedComparator(new EmployeeGroupComparator(), new EmployeeSalaryComparator()));
       }
   }

   public class Q62447064 {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Employee("emp1", "grp1", 500),
                   new Employee("emp2", null, 600), new Employee("emp3", null, 700), new Employee("emp4", "grp2", 800),
                   new Employee("emp5", "grp1", 700), new Employee("emp6", "grp2", 1000),
                   new Employee("emp7", "grp1", 800), new Employee("emp8", null, 1000),
                   new Employee("emp9", "grp2", 600)));

           // Sort employees using the comparators defined in the class, Solution
           new Solution().sortEmployees(empList);

           // Group employees by group ID with the sum of salary as the grouping function
           Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
           for (Employee e : empList) {
               String grp = e.getGroupId();
               if (grp == null) {
                   grp = "null";
               }
               Integer salary = map.get(grp);
               map.put(grp, salary == null ? e.getSalary() : e.getSalary() + salary);
           }

           // Result list
           List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<>();

           // Iterate the sorted entry set of `map` and put the records corresponding to
           // an entry into the result list
           for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : entriesSortedByValues(map)) {
               String grp = entry.getKey();
               int i;

               // Find the starting index of `grp` in empList

               if ("null".equals(grp)) {// Special handling for employees with `null` group
                   // Find the index in `empList` where employees with the group as `null` starts
                   for (i = 0; i < empList.size() && empList.get(i).getGroupId() != null; i++)
                       ;

                   // Add elements before a different group is encountered
                   for (int j = i; j < empList.size() && empList.get(j).getGroupId() == null; j++) {
                       result.add(empList.get(j));
                   }
               } else {
                   // Find the index in `empList` where employees with the group as `grp` starts
                   for (i = 0; i < empList.size() && !grp.equals(empList.get(i).getGroupId()); i++)
                       ;

                   // Add elements before a different group is encountered
                   for (int j = i; j < empList.size() && grp.equals(empList.get(j).getGroupId()); j++) {
                       result.add(empList.get(j));
                   }
               }
           }

           // Display result list
           for (Employee e : result) {
               System.out.println(e);
           }
       }

       private static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> SortedSet<Map.Entry<K, V>> entriesSortedByValues(
               Map<K, V> map) {
           SortedSet<Map.Entry<K, V>> sortedEntries = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<K, V>>(new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
               @Override
               public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> e1, Map.Entry<K, V> e2) {
                   int res = e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());
                   return res != 0 ? res : 1;
               }
           });
           sortedEntries.addAll(map.entrySet());
           return sortedEntries;
       }
   }
   ```

   **Output:**

   ```
   Employee [empId=emp6, groupId=grp2, salary=1000]
   Employee [empId=emp4, groupId=grp2, salary=800]
   Employee [empId=emp9, groupId=grp2, salary=600]
   Employee [empId=emp8, groupId=null, salary=1000]
   Employee [empId=emp3, groupId=null, salary=700]
   Employee [empId=emp2, groupId=null, salary=600]
   Employee [empId=emp7, groupId=grp1, salary=800]
   Employee [empId=emp5, groupId=grp1, salary=700]
   Employee [empId=emp1, groupId=grp1, salary=500]
   ```

   **Note:** The method, `entriesSortedByValues` has been copied from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4702335/10819573).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer I came up with. Its rather a crude solution but its working.

```
Collections.sort(list,
                new EmployeeChainedComparator(new EmployeeGroupComparator(), new EmployeeSalaryComparator()));

        List<Employee> emps = new ArrayList<>();

        while (!list.isEmpty()) {
            int max = list.get(0).getSalary();
            int currMax = 0;
            String currMaxGroup = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                if (i != list.size() - 1 && ((list.get(i).getGroupId() != null && list.get(i + 1).getGroupId() != null
                        && list.get(i).getGroupId().equals(list.get(i + 1).getGroupId()))
                        || (list.get(i).getGroupId() == list.get(i + 1).getGroupId())))
                    max = max + list.get(i + 1).getSalary();
                else if (i == list.size() - 2) {
                    max = max + list.get(i + 1).getSalary();
                    if (max > currMax) {
                        currMax = max;
                        currMaxGroup = list.get(i).getGroupId();
                        max = 0;
                    }
                } else if (max > currMax) {
                    currMax = max;
                    currMaxGroup = list.get(i).getGroupId();
                    max = 0;
                }

                if (i != list.size() - 1 && ((list.get(i).getGroupId() != null && list.get(i + 1).getGroupId() != null
                        && !list.get(i).getGroupId().equals(list.get(i + 1).getGroupId()))
                        || (list.get(i).getGroupId() != list.get(i + 1).getGroupId())))
                    max = list.get(i + 1).getSalary();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                if (currMaxGroup == null && list.get(i).getGroupId() == null) {
                    emps.add(list.get(i));
                    list.remove(list.get(i));
                    i--;
                } else if (currMaxGroup != null && currMaxGroup.equals(list.get(i).getGroupId())) {
                    emps.add(list.get(i));
                    list.remove(list.get(i));
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
```

After this the emps ArrayList will have the desired result.