# Sorting the values in the treemap

Tags: java

I read a text file and stored in a Tree map with each key having multiple values.Like,

key: A1BG   values: G5730  A4527  E3732  B0166

key: BCA3   values: C1478  A4172  D8974  B1432 E2147

key: DB8C   values: N0124  K7414  X9851

Since it is tree map I got all the keys sorted.Now,I want to sort all those values corresponding to the key.And get o/p As,

key: A1BG   values: A4527  B0166  E3732  G5730

key: BCA3   values: A4172  B1432  C1478  D8974  E2147

key: DB8C   values: K7414  N0124  X9851

Iam new to java.Can anyone help over this. Here is my code

```
BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\book\\datasone.txt"));
Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String,String>();
String currentLine;
while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) 
{
  String[] pair  = currentLine.split("\\s+");
  key = pair[0];
  value = pair[1];
  if(map.containsKey(key))
  {
    value +=  map.get(key);
  }
  else
  {
    map.put(key,value);    
  }
}
for (String name: map.keySet())
{
  String key =name.toString();
  String value = map.get(name).toString();  
  System.out.println(key + " " + value+ " ");  
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a treemap based on its values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448369/how-to-sort-a-treemap-based-on-its-values)

Answer (score 1):

If there are no duplicate values then you could store the values as a TreeSet

```
public class TestMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> lines = new ArrayList();
        lines.add("A1BG G5730");
        lines.add("A1BG A4527");
        lines.add("A1BG E3732");
        lines.add("A1BG B0166");
        lines.add("BCA3 C1478");
        lines.add("BCA3 A4172");
        lines.add("BCA3 D8974");
        lines.add("BCA3 B1432");
        lines.add("BCA3 E2147");
        lines.add("DB8C N0124");
        lines.add("DB8C K7414");
        lines.add("DB8C X9851");

        Map<String, Set<String>> map = new TreeMap<String,Set<String>>();
        for(String currentLine : lines){
            String[] pair  = currentLine.split("\\s+");
            String key = pair[0];
            String value = pair[1];
            if(!map.containsKey(key)){
                Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
                map.put(key,set);
            }
            map.get(key).add(value);
        }
        for (String name: map.keySet())
        {
            String key =name.toString();
            System.out.print(key);
            for (String value : map.get(name)){
                System.out.print(" " + value);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
A1BG A4527 B0166 E3732 G5730
BCA3 A4172 B1432 C1478 D8974 E2147
DB8C K7414 N0124 X9851
```

Comment: It stores the garbage data into values. Can u please help me to figure this out..

Answer (score 0):

Since all the values are stored in the `Map` as `String`s separated by space, you will have to post-process the `Map` (ie, process it after you've finished reading it)...

Basically, I would extract each value, split them on the space character into a `String[]` and use `Arrays#sort` to sort them.  Reproduce the `String` value and set it back as the value for the specified key.

For example...

```
for (String name: map.keySet())
{
  String key = name.toString();
  String value = map.get(name).toString();  
  String[] parts = value.split(" ");
  Arrays.sort(parts);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.length());
  for (String part : parts) {
    if (sb.length() != 0) {
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    sb.append(part);
  }
  map.put(key, value);
}
```

It might be easier to start with a `SortedMap<String, SortedSet<String>>`.  That way you could sort the values as your are reading the file, but you'd have to still post process the file to generate the `SortedMap<String, String>` map you are using.

This, of course, assumes that there are no duplicates values ;)

If there are duplicate values, you could use `SortedMap<String, List<String>>` instead.  But you would need to post process the map after you finish loading it, using something Collections.sort(List) to sort the `List` associated with each key in the `Map` and produce the `String` value you want...

**SortedSet example**

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("datasone.txt"));
    Map<String, SortedSet<String>> map = new TreeMap<String, SortedSet<String>>();
    String currentLine;
    while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] pair = currentLine.split("\\s+");
        String key = pair[0];
        String value = pair[1];
        SortedSet<String> set = map.get(key);
        if (set == null) {
            set = new TreeSet<String>();
            map.put(key, set);
        }
        set.add(value);
    }
    for (String name : map.keySet()) {
        String key = name.toString();
        SortedSet<String> set = map.get(key);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
        sb.append(key).append(":");
        for (String value : set) {
            sb.append(" ").append(value);
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Which reads...

```
A1BG G5730 
A1BG A4527 
A1BG E3732 
A1BG B0166
BCA3 C1478 
BCA3 A4172 
BCA3 D8974 
BCA3 B1432 
BCA3 E2147
DB8C N0124 
DB8C K7414 
DB8C X9851
```

And generates...

```
A1BG: A4527 B0166 E3732 G5730
BCA3: A4172 B1432 C1478 D8974 E2147
DB8C: K7414 N0124 X9851
```

Comment: Never seen SortedMap<String>, perhaps you mean SortedSet or List?

Comment: @Taylor Ahh, back to bed I think :P